# JSON won't work in Prism environment

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, prism

In a project WITHOUT the Prism library I had this code working to get a collection of "Persoon" objects:

```
 Dim ObjectCollectie As New ObservableCollection(Of Persoon)()
        If MijnAPIResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode Then

            Dim AntwoordVanAPI = Await MijnAPIResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
            ObjectCollectie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ObservableCollection(Of Persoon))(AntwoordVanAPI)
```

This code refers to a WebAPI to fetch the data and everything works fine.

This same statement won't work in the Prism ViewModel. It goes perfect until the ObjectCollectie is trying to use the JsonConvert statement. The AntwoordVanAPI contains the same JSON string like before.

The error message I get is:

```
 __The API 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1[[Dossier365.BusinessModels.Persoon, Dossier365.BusinessModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ff36822ea527de6]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List1[Dossier365.BusinessModels.Persoon])' cannot be used on the current platform. See  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.__
```

This refers to a nonexisting page on the Internet (I have seen more than a few complaints about that!). It is not easy to find anything recent on the subject "API cannot be used". The newest posts were about 2 years old.

Because the code has not changed, I suspect the Prism library. But why? And how to overcome? I have posted this on the CodePlex Prism issuelist as well, but I get the impression that only a few readers are active there. No response for over a week on issues. I hope StackOverflow does a better job.

Please, PLEASE, anyone knows an answer to this??

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of hours of comparning the code and about everything else, I finally figured out that the cause of this error lies in JSON.Net version 6.0.4. After stepping back to JSON.Net version 6.0.3 everything worked perfectly again. I have reported this in the JSON project on CodePlex.